# CSS line-height on mobile browsers (iOS)

Tags: html, ios, css, sass, cross-browser

What I am trying to do using HTML and CSS is simple: Create a notebook lines effect.
There are blog posts all over the web presenting a simple solution for rendering the lines using this: (snippet below in SCSS)

```
.notebook-effect{
  background-image: linear-gradient(grey 1px, transparent 1px);
  background-size: 100% $line-height;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;}
```

On all **desktop browsers it works like a charm**. However, on **iOS** safari and chrome the lines and text get very much out of phase.

This codepen might clarify the issue, open it on your mobile device:
 https://codepen.io/viiana/pen/MXObLj?editors=1000


**Just to clear out some questions:**
The codepen above is just the buggy part of a larger project that I am doing on CSS typography, you're welcome to check it out:
 https://github.com/SenhorLucas/LUV-Typography
Tried codepen, tried creating a localhost with node (browserSynch), then mamp, still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Okey, solved it with:
     `text-size-adjust: none;`

Some mobile browsers apply a text inflation factor if a mobile-first layout is not detected. This means that if I set my base text size to 1rem, the mobile browser will display it larger, at say, 1.5 rem in order to improve readability.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-size-adjust